# Displaying sub values in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, relationship

I'm working on a pretty large rails application and one of the tasks is to display a very large list of clients. Each client has multiple servers. I'm able to display all of the clients via the @client_name loop in the view. However, I'm unable to display each clients respective servers. (I hope this makes sense). To give a bit more context, when you access the clients index page, you can select on a client and a dropdown list of servers tied to that client is supposed to show up. The user can then select from that dropdown and will be redirected to that individual servers show page.

My controller looks like this

```
def index
 @nodes = Node.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 40
end

def node_filter
  @client_name =  @nodes.distinct.pluck(:client_name) 
  @hostname = @nodes.pluck(:hostname)
end
```

The index (view) looks like this (styling removed for clarity)

```
<% @client_name.each do |cn| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <p><%= cn %></p>
     <p><%=@hostname %></p> <!-- displaying ALL servers regardless of client ownership -->
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is acting exactly how you'd expect. Each dropdown has a list of all of the hosts. I tried creating a helper method that would iterate through the @hostname array, trying to match it to "cn" and displaying it but that didn't work out at all. I know there's an easy way to do this, I'm certain that I'm overthinking it and it's driving me crazy so I'm reaching out to the pros. Any advice, or help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, To make things easier this is a single table with client_name and hostname.

Comment: What's the data model - is there a relationship between clients and servers?

Comment: Initially I had clients and servers in separate tables, I put them in a single table to make things a bit cleaner. I'm just creating a table called "nodes" and the hostname and client_name are just strings.

Comment: So, the more I think about this, perhaps having client_name and hostname in the same table makes things harder.

going to split the tables to see if it's a bit easier for me. As of right now I'm on this silly hash creation train. Again, making it way more difficult than need be. I'll follow up with my findings shortly.

Comment: I meant is there a has_many relationship between clients and servers/hosts? and any relationship between nodes and servers?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken that would imply there is a relationship between multiple entities (tables). This was a single table so no, there wasn't a defined relationship.  That said, I was able to figure out the issue and it was actually related to the lack of relationship. Having a single table with these attributes and trying to access and display them the way I was is workable but definitely not scalable. I was able to fix my problem by creating a clients table and a devices table then building the relationship and displaying that way.

Comment: @margo - thank you for following up on this - I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That's what I would have suggested, kudos for figuring out a good solution. With a new application, its worth it to spend time working through the data model.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a relationship issue. Storing everything in a single table then trying to display the information the way I was required me to try to do silly parsing to get things to display how I needed them. Instead, splitting the tables and creating the appropriate relationships between them allowed me to easily query and display what I needed.